# How can I apply color to text following a specific string in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conditional-formatting, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I would like everything in the same line I type after a `#` to be RGB(98, 0, 196) and everything after `##` to be RGB(0, 180, 180)

This would ideally apply within the current style but I don't mind if the rule applies to the whole document

This is what I mean:

[image: What I mean]

I messed around with field variables but I could only figure out how to apply one of 8 colors to a number rather than any RGB color to text

Comment: I assume that you mean automatically, in real-time, via a macro. You should edit you question and add the code you have tried so far. The `cursor` has various attributes, including `cursor.CharColor` which requires to be set, if memory serves, to an `int` representation of the Hex colour code.  So red = `int("ff0000", 16)`